# Pass a parameter into the name of a subroutine

Tags: subroutine, perl

Is there a way to choose a subroutine by means of a parameter passed to another subroutine? Something like this:

```
sub foo1 {
    # does stuff to @_
}

sub foo2 {
    # does other stuff to @_
}

sub foo3 {
    # does other stuff to @_
}

sub foo {
    my $whichsub = shift;
    my @fooed = foo.$whichsub @_;
    # does stuff to @fooed
}
```

where `foo.$whichsub` should be `foo1` or the like. Except that of course that doesn't work.

Comment: You can do that by passing subroutine reference as argument to the subroutine. Please make your question more meaningful so that you get better answers.

Comment: @MalliParitala, I don't know what's *meaningless* about my question. It makes sense to me, obviously, but I've tried to read it objectively as I can and it makes sense anyway. The first sentence of your comment, on the other hand, sounds like an answer (basically the same as [Borodin's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31970398) actually) rather than a [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Sorry @JQKP . I mean a piece of code that can be executed to reproduce the problem you face.

Comment: @JQKP: No, passing a reference to a subroutine is very different from passing an index into a dispatch table

Comment: @MalliParitala, the problem I face is "What piece of code can I execute to get the result described in the question above?". You want me to post a piece of code that be executed to reproduce that problem? Fine: how about `print 'What piece of code can I execute to get the result described in the question above?'`?

Comment: @Borodin, this may be worth asking separately, but would `foo($funct,$arg); sub foo{$funct->($arg)}` be very different from `foo($functlookup,$arg); sub foo{my $funct = $dispatch[$functlookup]; $funct->($arg)}`? Is there somewhere I can read more about the difference?

Comment: @JQKP: It will have the same effect. The question comes down to whether you want to identify your subroutines by references to them, by a numerical index, or perhaps another way such as a string (in which case you would use a hash insteadof an array). It all depends on your application

Comment: @JQKP, `"foo$whichsub"->(@_)` is what you are looking for. Bad practice. , which is why Borodin's suggested a dispatch table instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can build a dispatch table of subroutines. Something like this

```
my @foo_table = \(&foo1, &foo2, &foo3);

foo(2);

sub foo {
    my $whichsub = shift;
    die unless my $foosub = $foo_table[$whichsub-1];
    my @fooed = $foosub->(@_);

    # does stuff to @fooed
}

sub foo1 {
    # does stuff to @_
}

sub foo2 {
    # does other stuff to @_
}

sub foo3 {
    # does other stuff to @_
}
```

Comment: @mob: The reference operator is distributive and does what I wanted. Your version would take a double reference to `foo2` and `foo3`

Comment: FWIW, I generally find it more useful to use a hash for sub dispatching. e.g. `%table = ( foo => \&foo, bar => \&bar ); $table{$whichsub}->( @_ );`

Comment: @friedo: It depends entirely on what determines which subroutine is to be run. In this case the OP had `foo1`, `foo2` and `foo3` and was using an integer to choose between them so the obvious choice is an array, although I'm sure (I hope) that those aren't the real names of the subroutines. If instead you have `a`, `b` and `c` then yes, you want a hash

Comment: When using a dispatch table, you often don't even want named subroutines.  Just have `sub { ... }` right in the table definition.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done without a table:

```
sub foo {
    my $whichsub = shift;
    my $foosub = "foo".$whichsub;
    my @fooed = &$foosub(@_);

    # does stuff to @fooed
}
```